# how to have separate style and script tags for different templates in angular

Tags: angular, templates

i have a bootstrap template that have different styles and scripts for rtl and ltr version
i add theme in index.html file and it works correctly for ltr or rtl version separately
but i want to change css and js in my app based on user selection language
i try to do this with  Renderer2 or Document to add correct js or css to may page and remove prev version of that , but as its js files needs to refresh the page it was not work correctly)
... any way...
i want a way to have two separate index.html files with respect scripts and styles ... so that i can change it interchangeably? or any method to change them...

Answer (score 1):

you must use the javascript .

for example when use select the persian language you must change the html `direction` like this :

```
    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TranslationService {
    languages: Language[];
    private langIds: string[] = [];
    private currentLang = new BehaviorSubject<string>('en');
    currentLang$ = this.currentLang.asObservable();
    emojioneIR = emojioneIR;
    emojioneUK = emojioneUK;

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        this.initLanguages();
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        const currentLang = this.getCurrentLang();
        if (currentLang) {
            translate.use(currentLang.lang);
            this.changeDirection(currentLang.dir);
            this.currentLang.next(currentLang.lang);
        } else {
            translate.use('en');
            this.changeDirection('ltr');
            localStorage.setItem('language', 'en');
        }
        this.loadTranslations(enLang, faLang);
    }

    initLanguages(): void {
        this.languages = [{
            lang: 'en',
            name: 'English',
            dir: 'ltr',
            rtl:false,
            flag: this.emojioneUK
        },
        {
            lang: 'fa',
            name: 'فارسی',
            dir: 'rtl',
            rtl:true,
            flag: this.emojioneIR
        }
        ];
    }

    getSelectedLanguage(): any {
        return localStorage.getItem('language') || this.translate.getDefaultLang();
    }

    loadTranslations(...args: Locale[]): void {
        const locales = [...args];

        locales.forEach(locale => {
            // use setTranslation() with the third argument set to true
            // to append translations instead of replacing them
            this.translate.setTranslation(locale.lang, locale.data, true);

            this.langIds.push(locale.lang);
        });

        // add new languages to the list
        this.translate.addLangs(this.langIds);
    }
    setLanguage(lang): void {
        if (lang) {
            localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
            location.reload();
        }
    }

    changeDirection(dir: string): void {
        if (!dir) { dir = 'rtl'; }
        const cssRtl: any = document.getElementById('rtlStyle');
        if (dir === 'rtl') {
            //     cssRtl.disabled = false;
            document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
        } else {
            //    cssRtl.disabled = true;
            document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
        }
    }

    getCurrentLang(): Language {
        if (localStorage.getItem('language')) {
            const currentLang = localStorage.getItem('language');
            for (const item of this.languages) {
                if (item.lang === currentLang) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your responce. but this is not i mentioned. i want to change assets in index.html file.

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/frest-clean-minimal-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-template/24656841?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI46uys9zY6gIVgYbACh0T7wkOEAAYASAAEgLOLPD_BwE